# jquery condition not working with selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to use first select option as placeholder with value empty, it works fine but the issue is I'm removing the disable class in the button according to the selection of user, it's not working. When i remove selected attribute from the option it works then doesn't show the first option as placeholder.
Html code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    if ($("#situation").val() != "") {
      $("#calculate").removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#calculate").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
  $("select").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="situation">
  <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Live only</option>
  <option value="2">Living together</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn disabled">Calcualte</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `value` of a `disabled` `option` element cannot be read, so jQuery is returning `null`, not `""` as your code is checking for.

To fix this you can change the condition to work with the falsy nature of jQuery. You can also change the `if` condition to a single `toggleClass()` call, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#situation").change(function() {
    $("#calculate").toggleClass("disabled", !$(this).val());
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #CCC;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="situation">
  <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Live only</option>
  <option value="2">Living together</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn disabled">Calcualte</a>
```

Comment: The OP will need to remove `disabled` to re-select that first option.

Comment: Thats true, if required.